# Removing and returning value from linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

Given position, how would I go about returning the value of that given position, and also removing that value from the linked list?

What I have, I think, only works for removing a value, but not returning it.

```
int i;
node *tmp = head; 
for(i=0 ; i<pos; i++)
  tmp = tmp->next; 
node* tmp2 = tmp->next; 
tmp->next = tmp->next->next;
free(tmp2);
return 0;
```

Comment: Don't free it or copy this value to new allocated memory.

Comment: store the value in another variable then do free, then return that variable.

Comment: additionally you code is buggy, you don't check for end reached?

Answer (score 3):

Use some local memory for storing data and return it after deletion.

```
int i;
int data = 0;    //for storing data
node *tmp = head; 
for(i=0 ; i<pos && tmp != NULL; i++) //Added for checking end of list
  tmp = tmp->next; 
node* tmp2 = tmp->next; 
tmp->next = tmp->next->next;
data = tmp2->data; //copy data to local struct before deleting
free(tmp2);
return data; //return the data
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that position starts from 1.

```
int i;
int data=0;
node *temp;
node *del;
// Do manipulaion if list is not empty
if(head!=NULL)
{
    //handles removal of head    
    if(pos==1)
    {
       del=head;
       head=del->next;
       data=del->data;
    }
    else
   {       
       for(i=1,temp=head;i<pos-1 && temp!=NULL; i++,temp=temp->next); // Iterates till previous positon
       // handles if input position is greater than list size
       if(temp && temp->next)
       {
           del=temp->next;
           temp->next=del->next;
           data=del->data;
       }
   }

   free(del);
}
return data;
```